# Where is the "class outline view" in Netbeans for PHP?

Tags: php, netbeans

In Eclipse I have a class outline view which shows me the **members of my class**:

[image]

I installed NetBeans 6.9.1 but can't find a window which shows me a list of the methods etc. in the class I am working on. **Where can I find this?**

[image]

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It should be visible in the Navigator window (Window, Navigating, Navigator or Ctrl-7 on Windows).

[image]

BTW It might take a while to appear when you just open the project though, because NB scans your source for changes first.