# Is there any tool for sorting PHP class methods by name in code?

Tags: php, netbeans, ide, coding-style

I was wondering if there was any tool for sorting PHP code (the methods of a class by name, exactly). I've been searching with Google for a while, but I didn't find anything.

Edited: I had a lot of setter and getter methods that were mixed, I want to order them for code readability and for finding them easier. Of course, I prefer to group related methods instead of sorting all of them alphabetically, but in each group I prefer to have them sorted that way.

Comment: There is: cut/paste. ;)

Comment: Ok I'll bite. Fot the love of god: WHY!?

Comment: This is relativity old but should point you in the right direction http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758/tools-for-php-code-refactoring I personally don't see the need.

Comment: I have a lot of setter and getter methods that are mixed, I want to order them for code readability and for finding them easier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do NOT want to order your class methods alphabetically in the file itself. Code is easier to read when the methods that belong together are close to each other:

> Concepts that are closely related should be kept vertically close to each other [G10] […] We want to avoid forcing our readers to hop around through our source files and classes

<sup>from Martin, Clean Code, "Vertical Distance", pg. 80</sup>

If you need to view them alphabetically, use your IDE's dynamic Views instead. In Netbeans, this is called the Class Outline View. See [Where is the "class outline view" in Netbeans for PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756770/where-is-the-class-outline-view-in-netbeans-for-php) on how to enable this.

If you desperately want to do this with PHP for some reason, you can do it with the [Reflection API](http://php.net/Reflection):

```
// get all the methods
$reflector = new ReflectionClass('Foo');
$methods = $reflector->getMethods();

// sort methods alphabetically
usort($methods, function($method1, $method2) {
    return strcasecmp($method1->getName(), $method2->getName());
});

print_r($methods);
```

This will give you an array of [ReflectionMethod](http://php.net/ReflectionMethod) objects sorted by the method name.

Comment: Yes I know that Netbeans can do such task in one of those view panels,  and I still want to keep related methods together, I only wanted to sort some method 'groups' without copy/paste.

Comment: @xaguilars well, like I said, if it's only for displaying them somehow, you can do with Reflection. The Reflection API would also be the basis to rewrite the source file, but it takes some effort and is unreliable, due to the arbitrary nature source code can be written. It's likely not worth the effort. Just rearrange the code manually the next time you need to modify the file for something else.

Comment: I see it's not worth the effort like you said. thanks.